# Convert array to JSON for jqplot

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array called `$result` that I am trying to convert to JSON and the array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-10
            [amount_saved] => 700
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-9
            [amount_saved] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2014-07-8
            [amount_saved] => 900
        )

)
```

I need to convert it to make it look like the following JSON

```
[['2014-07-10', 700], ['2014-07-9', 500], ['2014-07-8', 900]];
```

If I do `json_encode($result)` I get the following output which is not what i need

`[{"date":"2014-07-10","amount_saved":"700"},{"date":"2014-07-9","amount_saved":"500"},{"date":"2014-07-8","amount_saved":"900"}]`

I will really appreciate if someone can help me in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
$json = json_encode(array_map('array_values', $result));
```